# 回答がコメントに変換されるのはどんな時でしょうか

Tags: サポート

前に質問に回答したのですが、`簡易回答がコメントに変換されました`と出ました。
ここで質問なのですが、回答がこのようにコメントに変換されるのはどんな時ですか？教えて下さい。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

メタSEから画像を引用すると、こういう表示になるケースですね。

[image: screen shot]

具体的な文字数などは不明ですが、StackExchangeネットワーク内の既存の質問へのリンクを含んだ短文の回答は、自動的にコメントに変換されるようです。

参考 [Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/286934)

自動で変換されるのはこれぐらいだと思いますが、コメントとして投稿されるべき内容が回答として投稿されていた場合、モデレーターが手動で回答をコメントに変換することがあります。この場合は上記のような表示にはなりません。