# スタック・オーバーフローでは何故短い回答がコメントに変換されるのですか？

Tags: サポート

スタック・オーバーフローにおいては本家Stack Overflowと同じように、短く自明な回答をしたときに、それが質問へのコメントに変換されることがあります。 特に「簡易回答がコメントに変換されました」という自動変換の仕組みがあります。より具体的には、回答が短く、かつリンクを含んでいる場合、自動変換されるようです。

この仕組みはStack Exchange Metaにおいて[悪い評価を受けています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment)。また、私自身が確認をしたわけではありませんが、サイトによっては[無効化されているようです](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167433/trivial-answer-conversion)。

より具体的には、[「python3 webサーバの起動　できない」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32784/python3-web%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%AE%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)という、コメントで解決した質問の回答をコミュニティWikiとして投稿しようとした際にこの変換が起こりました（コメントは削除済み）。後から来た利用者に分かりやすいよう回答しようとしたのに、コメントに変換されては意味がありません。

何故この機能がスタック・オーバーフローにあるのか分からないのですが、何か意味はあるのでしょうか。

---

参考

- [回答がコメントに変換されるのはどんな時でしょうか -- スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2196/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%8C%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E6%99%82%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)
- [解法を促す書き込みはコメント欄ではなく回答欄に書いてほしい -- スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1938/%E8%A7%A3%E6%B3%95%E3%82%92%E4%BF%83%E3%81%99%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AF%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E6%AC%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E6%AC%84%E3%81%AB%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84)
- [Answer appears automatically converted as a comment -- Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment)
- [Trivial answer conversion -- Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167433/trivial-answer-conversion)
- [Should I give short answers or comments? -- Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138738/should-i-give-short-answers-or-comments)
- [Stack Exchange Meta 上の convert-to-comment タグ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert-to-comment?sort=votes)

Comment: メモ: こういう場合はこの機能がはたらいた方が有用？ https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2619/19110