# 自己回答がコメントにされてしまうため、解決済みにできない

Tags: サポート

[ダウンロードされたファイルを削除したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40201/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

こちらの質問なのですが、自己解決したため、自己回答をしたところ、簡易回答？とやらでコメントとして投稿されてしまいました。
それ自体は別に構わないのですが、質問を解決済みにするには、どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

申し訳ありませんが、回答の中身を具体的に説明するなどしてもう少し長めの回答にし、再投稿してください。短文の回答は自動的に簡易回答としてコメントに変換されることがあります（[参考](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2196/19110)）。

私にとって簡易回答の仕組みは、なぜ存在するのかよく分からない代物です。以前その疑問を[メタ投稿したことがある](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2427/19110)のですが、いまだ解決していません。